# Finding the Bias of a Proportion Estimation

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

I am fresh to statistics, and I have been asked a question to aid my understanding of the concept of "bias" in statistical sampling, which I require some help in clarifying.

Suppose $p$ is the proportion of a population with a certain characteristic. We take a simple random sample $\{y_1,y_2,...y_n\}$ without replacement from the population. We can use $\hat{p}=\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{y_i}{n}$ to estimate the sample proportion. (For reference, $y_i=1$ if the $i^{th}$ element has the characteristic, and $y_i = 0$  otherwise.)

I am given that $E(y_i)=E(y_i^2)=p$, and $\sigma^2=Var(y_i)=p-p^2$. Suppose now I am to use $\tilde{\sigma}^2=\hat{p}-\hat{p}^2$ as an estimator to $\sigma^2$. Can I say if this would be an unbiased estimator, and if not, what would be the bias and how can I construct an unbiased estimator?

My understanding of bias is how far the estimated value "deviates" from the true value. In the case of variance, that would mean $\tilde{\sigma}^2=\hat{p}-\hat{p}^2$ does not match the population variance due to the sample size vs population size difference, in this case by a factor of $\frac{n}{N}$. Can someone kindly point out what is wrong with my understanding here, or guide me further along?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: To clarify, the estimated value $\tilde \sigma^2$ will likely deviate from the true value $\sigma^2$ just by chance. We say an estimator is unbiased if, on average (across all possible samples you could take), the average estimated value is the same as the true population value, i.e. ${\mathbb E}[\tilde\sigma^2] = \sigma^2$.


Can you compute what ${\mathbb E}[\tilde\sigma^2]$ is?

Comment: @user51547 My current concept is that $E(\tilde{\sigma}^2)=E(\hat{p})-E(\hat{p}^2)$. In which case, I know that $E(\hat{p})=p$, therefore $E(\tilde{\sigma}^2)=E(\hat{p})-E(\hat{p}^2)=E(p)-E(p^2)$, which would make it unbiased. I'm very unsure of what I'm doing though, just going on a limited hunch. Would you mind correcting me?

Comment: $E(\hat p) = p$ is true, but that doesn't imply $E(\hat p^2) = p^2$.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on that? I guess I understand why they're not the same, but how could I know what $E(\hat{p}^2)$ equals to?

Comment: Sure. To convince yourself, take for example $X\sim \text{Normal}(0,1)$. $E[X]=0$, but $E[X^2] >0$, since $X^2$ is always non-negative and >1 with some positive probability. (In fact, since $\text{Var}(X) = E[X^2]-E[X]^2$, we can conclude $E[X^2] = 1$.)



You could try working out what $E(\hat p ^2)$ is directly by expanding $\hat p^2 = \left(\sum_i \frac{y_i}{n}\right)^2$ into $n^2$ terms and using linearity of expectation. Or, if you already know $\text{Var}(\hat p)$, you could use the variance definition above.